# Xamarin clear Android Log

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

The question is pretty straightforward: is there a way how to clear the Android Log in Xamarin out of messages from previous runs?

I've tried looking everywhere, but there isn't any Android Log setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to be fixed in the newest Xamarin version.

Answer (score 1):

that Log only reflects the Android Logcat so open a terminal and move to:

(sdk folder)/platform-tools and issue

./adb logcat -c

Then in Android Log press "Reconnect".

I hope that helps.